# Email2Case not working after adding new trigger

Tags: trigger, email2case

I have 2 triggers on case and everything is running fine when using email2case.  I created another trigger to populate a custom field in case.  When the new trigger is activated the email 2 case doesn't create a case or any other functions that it usually does.  Why would this code create this behavior?

```
    for (Case caseObj :Trigger.new) {
        if(caseObj.Origin == 'Email') {
            EmailMessage toEmail = [SELECT ToAddress FROM EmailMessage WHERE Incoming = true LIMIT 1];
            String te = String.valueOf(toEmail);
            System.debug('Email To Address is ' + toEmail);
            caseObj.Customer_Support_Email__c = te;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are they three separate triggers or are you using a helper/utility class?

Comment: @Girbot They're separate triggers.  Do I need to bulkify them into one so I can control the order that they're fired?

Comment: If you're going to write a bunch of little triggers like this, I think you should put them into a class and use a trigger handler to do the rest

Comment: +1 with EricSSH. Plus remove that SOQL from within the for loop - you will hit governor limits with any mass insert or updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bulking all the triggers into a Master Trigger and calling out to the three separate triggers which I turned into classes.  I can't find the place I found a good example that I used, but I wanted to thank Girbot and EricSSH for pointing me in the right direction.